# Harman Kardon AVR-170 control over RS232

Tags: c, serial-port, hardware

I'd like to control my HarmanKardon AVR 170 over RS232 port.
But I'm unable to find any related documents.

All I found was obsolete and outdated:
http://www.harmankardon.com/resources/Brands/harmankardon/Products/ProductRelatedDocuments/en-US/TechnicalSheet/RS232%20Protocol.pdf

Does anybody have any information on this?
Stackoverflow might not be the best option to ask this but I have no other idea.

So if you have please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried emailing HK support to see if they can help you?

Comment: Yes, I tried. They don't look very supportive though.